# How can I reference the value in prior row of same column with SQL in Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

My background is in Excel modeling and I'm very new to SQL. I have a table that looks like the following. And I would like to create the 'desired_col' which assumes a 1 pct compounded monthly growth rate for forecast months in the forecast:

```
region | category       | date    | date_type | revenue | desired_col
---------------------------------------------------------------------
East   | Inventory      | 07/2017 | Actual    | 25      | 25
East   | Non-Inventory  | 07/2017 | Actual    | 20      | 20
West   | Inventory      | 07/2017 | Actual    | 18      | 18
West   | Non-Inventory  | 07/2017 | Actual    | 16      | 16
East   | Inventory      | 08/2017 | Forecast  | 0       | 25.25
East   | Non-Inventory  | 08/2017 | Forecast  | 0       | 20.2
West   | Inventory      | 08/2017 | Forecast  | 0       | 18.18
West   | Non-Inventory  | 08/2017 | Forecast  | 0       | 16.16
East   | Inventory      | 09/2017 | Forecast  | 0       | 25.5025
East   | Non-Inventory  | 09/2017 | Forecast  | 0       | 20.402
West   | Inventory      | 09/2017 | Forecast  | 0       | 18.3618
West   | Non-Inventory  | 09/2017 | Forecast  | 0       | 16.3216
```

Now, I can accomplish this for the first month in the forecast (August in my example above) using the LAG function:

```
CASE WHEN date_type = 'Actual' THEN revenue ELSE 
LAG( revenue , 1 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY region, category ORDER BY date ) * 1.01
END
```

But the above statement returns 0 for September and beyond. This is simple in Excel but I'm stumped here. Any suggestions you can give me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can identify the necessary offset based on the number of months between your last actual month and the forecast month and use it as dynamic offset for `LAG` and power for growth rate:

```
with 
get_offsets as (
    select *
    ,case when to_date(date,'MM/YYYY')>'2017-07-01' then datediff(month,'2017-07-01',to_date(date,'MM/YYYY'))::integer end as this_offset
    from your_table
)
select *
,case when date_type = 'Actual' then revenue 
 else lag(revenue, this_offset) over (partition by region, category order by date) * 1.01 ^ this_offset
 end
from get_offsets
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks so much! I was able to plug that right into the column with LAG(revenue,DATEDIFF(...)).....^(DATEDIFF(...))

Answer (score 0):

The LAG statement isn't working for Sep onwards because the Lag(1) will be looking at the zero in revenue for Aug.  Sep would be calculated using the zero in Aug, Oct would be calculated using the zero in Sep, etc. etc.

You would need to loop the LAG statement like this:

```
LAG( LAG( revenue , 1 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY region, category ORDER BY date ) * 1.01 , 1 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY region, category ORDER BY date ) * 1.01
```

...but you would need to do that for as many months as you want to forecast into the future.  I.E. VERY messy.

I think you are going to have to use a loop and variables (as un-SQL as that is).  But the good news it would be more in line with the Excel solution you're familiar with.